# why cannot we declare this.render inside togglestatus function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Started learning Backbone JS. Reading Codeschool docs. I just didn't understood why we need to declare `this.model.on('....')` in initialize, instead of just using `'this.render();'` in `toggleStatus` function. Please someone explain me clearly.

**Below is the code I copy-pasted from docs:**

**Before:**

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'change input': 'toggleStatus'
    },

    toggleStatus: function(){
        this.model.toggleStatus();
        this.render(); //Doesn’t work for other model changes  , WHY IT DOESN'T WORK??
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }

     }
});
```

**After:**

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
    'change input': 'toggleStatus'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    toggleStatus: function(){
        this.model.toggleStatus();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the articles though

First of all, why `this.render` doesn't work for other model changes is just because when `toggleStatus` is called in the `Before` code is only the time input change event fires.

So the flow is like...

1. a user change a input field value.
2. `this.events` receive the event and call `toggleStatus` and then `this.render` is called inside of the `toggleStatus`

in the `After` codes,You are calling `model.on` which is a function to set a listener for model events and `toggleStatus` is set as a callback function of it.

So,the flow would be...

1.Whenever the model gets changed,`model.on` gets the event and the callback function `this.render` is called.

which means whenver model properties get any changes,`this.render` is called.and Since `change input` calls `toggleStatus` which makes changes on the model(I don't know because You didn't put the code of it but I'm almost sure about it),input changes end up calling `this.render`(and also any other model properties changes calls this.render too)

AYI,I assume the articles are kinda old because `model.on` is not suitable to use anymore and better to use `listenTo` instead.Because `model.on` is hard to unbind events and it makes zombie View easily.

check more info http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo